# Is it correct to put h2 and h3 on top of image?

Tags: css, html, seo

I have few banners which are main categories on the website. I wish to display
title and subtitle on top of those images, and currently I am using the following structure:

```
        <a href="#" title="">

                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(1) );?>" alt="xy">
                    <h3>
                    <?php $post_title = get_post_custom_values('post_title', 1);
                        echo $post_title[0];    
                    ?>
                    </h3>
                    <h2>
                    <?php $post_subtitle = get_post_custom_values('post_subtitle', 1);
                        echo $post_subtitle[0]; 
                    ?>
                    </h2>                   
            </a>
```

Is this a good workaround? Is this correct html usage?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about search engine optimization.

Comment: why would `h3` come before `h2` ? That certainly doesn't make SEO or accessibility sense

Comment: It is not about search engine optimization, but html correctness.. and h3 comes before h2 since I wish to show a small subtitle and below the main subject. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Heading elements should not be used for subtitles. [From the W3C:](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/common-idioms.html#sub-head)

> h1–h6 elements must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles,
>   alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for
>   a new section or subsection.